# Polymer elements not working properly even after bower reinstall

Tags: polymer

Ok. This is my last resort until flipping the table and saying goodbye to Polymer for good. I've been trying for the past 3 days to do some basic stuff in Polymer but I haven't been able to do so. Between including some paper-elements ,and caching (which apparently not even disabling it from Chrome's toolbox seem to work) I don't know which is the one who is giving me the most headaches. There is also no way for me to debug the project. Enough rant...

I started to finally grasp the library, until I tried using the  `<paper-dropdown-menu>` and a custom element downloaded from github: `<simple-slider>`.

Simple Slider does not seem to work (does not show up the carousel correctly), and paper-dropdown-menu does not select the item.

All the dependencies have been successfully referenced (checking with Visual Studio Code), and the webComponents polyfill is included as well.

Here are my main .html files:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2015 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="generator" content="Polymer Starter Kit">
  <title>Polymer Starter Kit</title>

  <!-- Place favicon.ico in the `app/` directory -->

  <!-- Chrome for Android theme color -->
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#2E3AA1">

  <!-- Web Application Manifest -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <!-- Tile color for Win8 -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF">

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="application-name" content="PSK">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png">

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Polymer Starter Kit">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/touch/apple-touch-icon.png">

  <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144) -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">

  <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <!-- endbuild-->

  <!-- build:js bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js -->
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- Because this project uses vulcanize this should be your only html import
       in this file. All other imports should go in elements.html -->
  <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">

  <!-- For shared styles, shared-styles.html import in elements.html -->
  <style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>
</head>

<body unresolved>
  <!-- build:remove -->
  <span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">

    <pgarena-navbar></pgarena-navbar>
     <simple-slider style="width:100%; height:500px" auto-play="true">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/>
    </simple-slider>

    <div class="container">
      <paper-dropdown-menu label="Dinosaurs">
        <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
          <paper-item>allosaurus</paper-item>
          <paper-item>brontosaurus</paper-item>
          <paper-item>carcharodontosaurus</paper-item>
          <paper-item>diplodocus</paper-item>
        </paper-listbox>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>

    <pgarena-tournament-card>

        </pgarena-tournament-card>
        <pgarena-tournament-card>
        </pgarena-tournament-card>
        <pgarena-tournament-card>
        </pgarena-tournament-card>
        <pgarena-tournament-card>
        </pgarena-tournament-card>
    </div>


    <!-- Uncomment next block to enable Service Worker support (1/2) -->
    <!--
    <paper-toast id="caching-complete"
                 duration="6000"
                 text="Caching complete! This app will work offline.">
    </paper-toast>

    <platinum-sw-register auto-register
                          clients-claim
                          skip-waiting
                          base-uri="bower_components/platinum-sw/bootstrap"
                          on-service-worker-installed="displayInstalledToast">
      <platinum-sw-cache default-cache-strategy="fastest"
                         cache-config-file="cache-config.json">
      </platinum-sw-cache>
    </platinum-sw-register>
    -->

  </template>

  <!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild-->
</body>

</html>
```

Elements.html:

```
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2015 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->

<!-- Iron elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">

<!-- Paper elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/typography.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">

<!-- App Elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">


<!-- Custom Elements -->
<link rel="import" href="pgarena-navbar/pgarena-navbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="pgarena-container/pgarena-container.html">
<link rel="import" href="pgarena-tournament-card/pgarena-tournament-card.html">

<!-- 3rd Party Non Google -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer-simple-slider/src/simple-slider.html">


<!-- Uncomment next block to enable Service Worker Support (2/2) -->
<!--
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/platinum-sw/platinum-sw-cache.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/platinum-sw/platinum-sw-register.html">
-->

<!-- Configure your routes here -->
<link rel="import" href="routing.html">

<!-- Add your elements here -->
<link rel="import" href="../styles/app-theme.html">
<link rel="import" href="../styles/shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-greeting/my-greeting.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-list/my-list.html">
```

BTW: I tried reinstalling all the bower packages, but it did not work. Tried unzipping the latest Polymer into the bower_components folder and did not work.

Any ideas? I can't believe it's been this painful to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Simple Slider does not seem to work (does not show up the carousel correctly)

I assume you're referring to [polymer-simple-slider](https://github.com/ruyadorno/polymer-simple-slider). That project depends on Polymer 0.2.x, which is not compatible with the newest version of Polymer (1.10.1 as of this writing). If you're interested in upgrading that element, you could follow the [migration guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration). The element's source looks pretty trivial, and it wouldn't take much effort to upgrade IMO.

> paper-dropdown-menu does not select the item.

Please clarify what you mean. Selection works fine here:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.10.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/web-animations.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
</head>
<body>
  <paper-dropdown-menu label="Dinosaurs">
    <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
      <paper-item>allosaurus</paper-item>
      <paper-item>brontosaurus</paper-item>
      <paper-item>carcharodontosaurus</paper-item>
      <paper-item>diplodocus</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/beVjZr?editors=1000)</sup>

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaargh. I was missing paper-listbox @_@. 

tony, I'd like to take the chance and ask you for tips or recommendations when working with Polymer. How did you get to learn it? 

On a side note, thanks for letting me know that that module is for 0.2. I will not upgrade it as I'd rather implement something different (preferably with background-image and css so I can take advantage of the "cover" property of the background-size). Thanks a bunch.!!!

Comment: BTW, do you know how can I be sure that Google Chrome is not catching the html imports? I disabled a setting in the Developer Tools (Disable cache While DevTools is open)

Comment: I'm glad that helped. Aside from reading the docs, I learned Polymer by experimentation and grokking the source of individual elements and their demos. I use Webstorm, which lets me quickly jump into the source with CTRL-click. Before there was [Polymer App Toolbox](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/), I found [yeoman](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-polymer) helpful, and then came [PSK](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit) (which you're apparently using).

Comment: The DevTools Network tab should indicate whether the file is pulled from cache.

Comment: Hmmm I see. Seems that'll be the same path to take. On the other hand, I have good news! You've been of great help :D! I've made a big breakthrough through Polymer after reading your answer. I was able to do some basic layout in around 2 hours vs the 3 past days it took me to try to understand it.